# Pylint not showing ouput in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm trying to check for issues in a script I'm working on "python_record.py". If I run pylint python_record.py in a terminal I get a long output with multiple errors.

But when I run pylint through VSCode I don't get anything. I've enabled linting, and selected run pylint and it's giving me nothing. The following is my settings.json:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": -2,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\becky\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38- 
      32\\python.exe",
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    },
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    ],
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
    {
        "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
        "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
    }
]
```

}

[VSCOde settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OnqV.png)

I'm not fixed on any particularly fancy settings so happy to change the settings.json around completely, I just want my default terminal to be bash and linting to run properly (particularly on save).

Please let me know if you can help!

Thanks!!

Edit:

If I run `pip show pylint` in my VSCode terminal, the following is returned:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this, I resolved it by reinstalling VSCode and starting from scratch as follows:

1. Uninstalled VSCode
2. Deleted my "User/AppData/Roaming/Code" folder
3. Deleted my "User/[uname]/.vscode
4. re-installed VSCode, it was completely fresh with none of my old settings/ scripts open.
5. Installed VSCode extras that I needed (Python, WSL and Pylint extensions)
6. ran `pip install pylint` in my terminal
7. ran `pylint --generate-rcfile | Out-File -Encoding utf8 .pylintrc` in my terminal from the folder where my scripts are (not sure if I'll have to do this every time!)
8. Restarted VSCode and it worked fine!

(The locations of the folders you need to delete may be different I had to dig about a bit for mine. I also couldn't see them in my usual file explorer so I had to go through the command line - I use a bash emulator)

[This website](https://medium.com/@yashshavikashyap/linting-python-in-visual-studio-code-687061f43ad9) was helpful:

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the module "pylint" is already installed in the python environment currently used in VS Code: (`pip show pylint`)

[image]

If it does not display the information of the module "pylint", you could use "pip" to install it in this environment: `pip install pylint`; or you could switch the python environment to the one that has "pylint" installed.

"Pylint" information will be automatically displayed here:

[image]

Reference: [Pylint in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_enable-linters) and [Python Environment in VSCode.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: Hey! running pip show pylint returns a full output as expected, I'll put the output as an edit in the main question

Comment: @Becky Heath -Have you tried reloading VS Code? Please try to reinstall "pylint".

Comment: I just ran a pip install of pylint, and I upgraded pylint. I then closed VSCode and started it up again and the problem is still there!

Comment: @Becky Heath -What extensions have you used in VS Code? And since there are two "[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)" in VS Code, it is recommended that you check whether "Pylint" is set in the other "settings.json".

Comment: Oh! How would I find the other one? This "settings.json" was found through VSCode Settings?

Comment: @Becky Heath  -You can click _F1_ to open the VS Code command panel, and then enter "_Preferences: Open User Settings_" or "_Preferences: Open Workspace Settings_".

Comment: thank you for your help, but I managed to resolve this by resinstalling VSCode and starting from scratch!